# Contradiction in Ampere's Circuital Law

Tags: electromagnetism

---

So, we have an infinite current carrying wire carrying a current I coming out of the plane and we want to calculate the value of integral of B.dl along the infinite straight line path AB(in the plane of paper) at any distance from it. Now, if we take an amperian path of AB and a symmetrical straight line path placed on the other side of the wire(as shown in image), the paths joined by straight lines placed at infinite distance from current carrying wire the value of integral of B.dl along AB and other path is same(because of symmetry) and along the other two lines it is 0(because B is 0 at infinity), so value of integral of B.dl along AB is ui/2. But, if we take the other path to be also placed at infinte distance from wire integral of B.dl throught it will also be 0, so it's value along AB is ui. Where am I going wrong, pls explain.
(u= permeability of free space)

[image]

Comment: Hello! It is preferable to use MathJax (LaTeX) to display formulas. You can find a tutorial at [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/). Please [edit] your question accordingly. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

"At infinity" is a tricky concept, because you end up with multiplying the "zero at infinity" field with the infinite length of the path, and $0\cdot\infty$ is indeterminate. To get back on solid ground you need to work with "towards infinity" instead, and consider what happens when the dimension gets *very large* but is still finite.

(In mathematical jargon, this is described as "in the limit", but don't let this suggestive terminology fool you into thinking that "the limit" is somewhere concrete that you can actually have a path going through. Going to the limit is a *process*, not a *destination*).

In the calculation that works, the horizontal parts *stay the same length* while you increase the vertical dimension, and *therefore* you can say that their contribution to the integral drops solidly towards zero as you take the limit. If you also moved the left boundary away from the wire, the horizontal parts of the path would need to increase in length, and you can't say with certainty that their contributions drop away (which in fact they won't).